# String.Format an integer to use a thousands separator with decimal value in danish culture

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a string  `totalPRice` which holds a value like this `1147,5` 
I want two things.
1)round the value so that there is always two digits after `,`
2)Implement thousands separator in this string, So that final out put will be some thing like this `1.147,50`
I have tried some thing like this

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}", totalPRice)
```

It does my first requirement correctly by producing an output `1147,50`.
But I am way behind in my second requirement. Can any one tell me how I can achieve this?

**Note: In danish culture `.` stands for `,` and `,` stands for `.`**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can refer to [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and use

```
string.Format("{0:N2}", 1234.56)
```

You may also specify the culture manually, if danish is not your default culture:

```
var danishCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("da-DK");
string.Format(danishCulture, "{0:N2}", 1234.56);
```

see [MSDN Reference for CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/System.Globalization.CultureInfo%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
String.Format("{0:N2}", totalPRice)
```

Another possibility is to use the `ToString(string format)` overload.

```
totalPRice.ToString("N2");
```

Answer (score 2):

You should create a culture-specific [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Globalization.CultureInfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object and use it when converting the number into a string. Also, you can set the [default culture for your whole program](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Then, your code will look like this:

```
// create Dennmark-specific culture settings
CultureInfo danishCulture = new CultureInfo("da");

// format the number so that correct Danish decimal and group separators are used
decimal totalPrice = 1234.5m;
Console.WriteLine(totalPrice.ToString("#,###.##", danishCulture));
```

Note that `.` and `,` in the formatting string are specified opposit as you want. This is because they identify decimal and group separators, and are replaced with the correct culture specific-ones.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a currency value (money!), then it's better to use the current format specifier 'C' or 'c':

```
string.Format("{0:C}", 1234.56)
```

Normally I don't write the number of decimal digits since it comes from the international configuration. 
You may way to use a different colture specifier if you don't want to use the default one.

```
var colture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("§§§§§");
string.Format(culture, "{0:C}", 1234.56);
```

where §§§§§ is the string that identifies the desired colture.

Answer (score -2):

Try this for Price format. Put it under template field instead of BoundField.

```
<%#(decimal.Parse(Eval("YourDataField").ToString())).ToString("N2")%>
```

Comment: <%# (decimal.Parse(Eval("Your DataField").ToString())).ToString("N2")%>