# How to format Danish currency with .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, internationalization, cultureinfo, culture

I am using C# with .NET 4.7.2 and working with **Danish currency**. I am unable to achieve correct formatting. Here is my code that I have hardcoded for illustration purposes:

```
decimal val = 10946;
CultureInfo formatCulture = new CultureInfo("da-DK");
string formattedNumber = string.Format(formatCulture, "{0:kr. #.##0.00;kr. -#.##0.00}", val);
```

Actual result: `kr10946, 000000`

Desired result: `kr10.946`

The thousands "comma separator" should be a period, and they don't want any decimals.

How can I achieve desired formatting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format price in Danish with curency symbol on right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17773283/format-price-in-danish-with-curency-symbol-on-right) and [String.Format an integer to use a thousands separator with decimal value in danish culture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20396560/string-format-an-integer-to-use-a-thousands-separator-with-decimal-value-in-dani) and [DataFormatString for currency is not working for danish culture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23630076/format-a-decimal-to-correct-currency-using-correct-number-of-decimals-c)

Comment: In format strings comma represents the thousandth separate and period is the decimal separator.  Then when formatting the culture determines the actual character used, so you'd want `kr#,##0.00` not `kr. #.##0.00`

Comment: juharr, that worked perfectly. Can you post that as the answer for others' benefit? Also, I removed the `.00` to remove the decimals and it's perfect.